# JQuery alert on TD click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My project doesn't alert "Test" when I click on any of the "td" Elements.

I will use it for something more useful later but I'm just trying to get it to alert on click, Thank you!

link: http://jsfiddle.net/gk5c9z2z/

```
 $("td").click(function () {
      alert("Test");
  });
```

Comment: Use the JQuery `each` method.

Comment: You have an error : `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`

Answer (score 3):

`for (var i = 0; i <= Cards.length; 0) {` line is the culprit. The last iteration fails as `Cards[i]` returns `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have `setAttribute` method. JavaScript interpreter throws an error and subsequent lines are not executed. Change it to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Cards.length; 0) {
```

Also note that you could use `i++` instead of `0` as the final-expression of the `for` loop and remove the `i = i + 1;` line.

Comment: you beat me to it :) also please always check your console before posting questions, the console errors help :D

P.S. image Tag is self closing so that is <img.... /> not <img></img>

Comment: I know I did see the console, the console error I didn't know how to fix but I didn't think it was leading to this error, Thank you very much this fixed my problem. <3

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$("td image")
```

as you are really clicking on the image.